# Unable to disable time only field on CRM form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm trying to disable all fields on Dynamics 365 CE form using javascript using the following code:

```js
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attribute) {
   var control = Xrm.Page.getControl(attribute.getName());

   if (control) {
      control.setDisabled(true)
   }
});
```

All fields on the form are disabled except the time only field. My form looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Xrm.Page` object, which is now deprecated.

Instead use the context passed to the onLoad function of your form. Try this:

```js
function onLoad(context) {
   var formContext = context.getFormContext();

   formContext.data.attributes.forEach(a => {
      a.controls.forEach(c => {
         if (c.getControlType() !== "kbsearch")
            c.setDisabled(true);
      });
   });
}
```

> According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/setdisabled) control type KB Search should be the only control type not supporting `setDisabled()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
 Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, i) {
            if (control && control.getDisabled && !control.getDisabled()) {
                control.setDisabled(true);
            }
        });
```